# Help: creating new categories in order to merge 2 datasets

Tags: spss, dataset

I have a dataset for the years 2000-2005 and another for 2006-2008.

In the first dataset, I have the following age groups: 0-14 years, 15-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59 and 60 and above. In the second one, I have: 0-5 years, 5-14, 15-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65-74, 75 and above. The data under these categories is binary (0-1).
In the first dataset, I have another variable providing the age of all the subjects. I don't have such information in the second dataset (I just have the age groups mentioned above with 0-1 entries).

I wish to merge both datasets. I need to recategorize the age groups into maybe: 15-24, 22-34, 35-64, 65 and above. I could merge the categories in the years 2006-2008, and use the age variable to create these categories in the first dataset.

How is this done on spss? I need step-by-step instructions please.

I am looking forward to your reply. Many many thanks.

Comment: You want to re-categorize the age groups into 15-24, 22-34, 35-64, and 65+? Is 22 in 22-34 group a typo? It overlaps with the previous group.

Comment: You are right. It is a typing error. I meant 25-34. Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the RECODE command, Transform > Recode into Different Variables

Comment: Yes, I used the 'recode into different variables' to form the groups for 2000-2005 from the 'age' variable. But, for the dataset 2006-2008, I have 'age groups'only so how do I merge the existant groups when they are in binary code? How do I merge, for instance, age groups 35–44 and 45-54? I can't use the recode command. Looking forward to your reply. Happy New Year!

Comment: Please, someone help me with this :)

Comment: I realize my questions are too simple and boring for experts. I have 2-3 questions that I really need to answer so I can proceed with my analysis. Can anyone please give me a link to another active spss forum.